# Android remote XML parse (document builder)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

i have been traipsing the internet for days and i really need some help, i am trying to parse in an XML document from a web server into a ListView in android, i have worked out how to do it with a local file and that is fine, but no matter what i find whether on stack or other sites it just doesnt seem to work, can anyone help me with this?? i know the page exists and works...ive pulled all my hair out now so pleas help :)

below is my code for the method, this is called after the on create and an onclicklistener for items,also i am using the document builder factory method.

```
private void xmlparse()
{

    try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new URL("URL in here").openConnection().getInputStream());

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

               Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
               if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                  Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                  titles.add(getTagValue(TITLE_1, eElement));  //TITLE_1 is the xml tag title

               }
            }


          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
}

private String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

            Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

        return nValue.getNodeValue();
     }
```

Am i missing something daft or have i missed the ball completely? can anyone point me to infomation which would help or just let me know :)

Cheers!!

Comment: Does anyone have any information for me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I've made which do that task, you should do this following :

```
                //Formattage des strings pour le passage en URL
                from = URLEncoder.encode(from, "UTF-8");
                to = URLEncoder.encode(to, "UTF-8");
                String addressToConnect = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins="+from+"&destinations="+to+"&mode=driving&units="+unit+"&sensor=false";

                //Partie connexion
                URL url = new URL(addressToConnect);
                HttpURLConnection connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connexion.connect();
                InputSource geocoderResultInputSource;
                geocoderResultInputSource = new InputSource(connexion.getInputStream());

                //Partie XML/XPATH

                Document geocoderResultDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(geocoderResultInputSource);
                XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

                //On s'assure que la requete envoy�e � l'API � bien renvoy�e un STATUS = OK cf. Google API
                NodeList nodeListCodeResult = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//status", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

etc...

Hope it helps,